# How to remove currency amounts from a list? ["9.358,26 €", "Hello World", "3.562,77 €", "3,77 €"] -> ["Hello World"]

Tags: currency, sign, euro

["9.358,26 €", "Hello World", "3.562,77 €", "3,77 €"] -> ["Hello World"]

I was thinking of using regex, but is there a more easy way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Python, a simple [List Comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) should suffice:

```py
lst = ["9.358,26 €", "Hello World", "3.562,77 €", "3,77 €"]
[el for el in lst if "€" not in el]
>>> ["Hello World"]
```

Another option is using the [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp) function:

```py
def contains_currency(s):
    return "€" not in s

list(filter(contains_currency, lst))
```

more compactly using an [anonymous function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp):

```py
list(filter(lambda s: "€" not in s, lst))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Javascript, a simple [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should suffice:

```js
let array = ["9.358,26 €", "Hello World", "3.562,77 €", "3,77 €"];

filteredArray = array.filter((item) => !item.includes('€'));

console.log(filteredArray);
// ["Hello World"]
```

Read more about the `includes()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).